# How to control the scientifc style of NSNumberFormatter?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm converting a long string representing a very big or small number to a string in scientific notation. E.g. 9999999999999999999999999 to 9.999999999999999E24.

I use NSNumberFormatter.

```
NSNumberFormatter *ns = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[ns setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle];
NSString *result = [ns stringFromNumber: [ns numberFromString: aBigOrSmallString]];
[ns release];
```

But how can I control the precision part? For example, from 912345678 to 9.12E8 or 9.1234E8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the `setMinimumFractionDigits` and `setMaximumFractionDigits`
Reference: [NSNumberFormatter Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setMinimumFractionDigits:)