# Number formatting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Hi all I am using below method to get string from NSNumber

```
     -(NSString *)stringFromNumber:(NSNumber *)number
    {
        NSLog(@"Input:---%@",number);
        NSNumberFormatter *numFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        [numFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:5];
        [numFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
        //[numFormatter setExponentSymbol:@"e"];
        NSString *str_num = [numFormatter stringFromNumber:number];
        NSLog(@"Output:---%@",str_num);
        return str_num;
    }
```

in console i am getting like below

```
    Input:---2.940000057220459
    Output:---2.94                
    Input:---2940.000057220459
    Output:---2940.00006         
    Input:---2.940000057220459e-15
    Output:---.00                 
    Input:---2.940000057220459e-12
    Output:---.00                 
    Input:---2.940000057220459e-09
    Output:---.00                 
    Input:---2.940000057220459e-06
    Output:---.00                 
    Input:---0.002940000057220459
    Output:---.00294
```

but I need the output to look like below for above inputs (order)

```
---2.94
---2940
---2.94e-15
---2.94e-12
---2.94e-6
---2.94e-9
---0.00294
```

How would I do it? Someone please help me.

Comment: i think this should do it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215867/how-to-control-the-scientifc-style-of-nsnumberformatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried this

```
-(NSString *)stringFromNumber:(NSNumber *)number
{
    NSLog(@"Input:---%@",number);
    NSNumberFormatter *numFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:5];
    [numFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
    NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",number];
    NSRange range = [temp rangeOfString:@"e"];
    if(range.length > 0){
        [numFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle];
        [numFormatter setExponentSymbol:@"e"];
    }
    NSString *str_num = [numFormatter stringFromNumber:number];
    NSLog(@"Output:---%@",str_num);
    return str_num;
}
```

and Got like this

```
Input:---2.940000057220459
Output:---2.94
Input:---2940.000057220459
Output:---2940.00006
Input:---2.940000057220459e-15
Output:---2.94e-15
Input:---2.940000057220459e-12
Output:---2.94e-12
Input:---2.940000057220459e-09
Output:---2.94e-9
Input:---2.940000057220459e-06
Output:---2.94e-6
Input:---0.002940000057220459
Output:---.00294
```

Comment: second input has got an output as you want ?? did you notice that

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [NSNumberFormatter Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setMinimumFractionDigits%3a).

```
setMinimumFractionDigits:  
setMinimumIntegerDigits:
```